# Between Date ranges query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, between

I have a simple query to grab date between a couple of date ranges. It runs in about 10 seconds but I would like to improve its performance if possible.
Thanks in advance

```
declare @Fst_LY date, @Lst_LY date, @Fst_TY date, @Lst_TY date

----------------------------------------------
set @Fst_TY ='4/1/18'   --First day this year
set @Lst_TY ='4/30/18'  --Last day this year
----------------------------------------------
set @Fst_LY ='4/2/17'   --First day last year
set @Lst_LY ='5/1/17'   --Last day last year
----------------------------------------------

select distinct  hyp as H
    from myView
where       
([Contract] between  @Fst_LY  and  @Lst_LY)  or ([Contract] between @Fst_TY  and  @Lst_TY))
```

Comment: The speed all depends on your view.

Comment: Please show an execution plan, and tag your question with whatever database you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to the Execution Plan. I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Try using union instead of or:

```
select  hyp as H
        from myView
    where       
     [Contract] between  @Fst_LY  and  @Lst_LY
    union  
    select  hyp as H
        from myView
    where       
     [Contract] between  @Fst_TY  and  @Fst_LY
```

Comment: Try UNION ALL if there are no duplicates or having duplicate data is fine. This will speed up processing further